# Python: Parsing a log file without convenient delimiters or fixed-width

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am struggling with a stupidly simple problem. I am trying to parse a .log file that looks like the following:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-03-31 00:00:40
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-03-31 00:00:40 172.33.22.75 GET /alcatel_tracfone_phone.html - 443 - 12.123.23.456 okhttp/3.12.1 - 200 0 0 32
...
2020-03-31 00:01:03 172.33.22.75 GET /jose_laptop_windows.html - 443 - 170.173.81.52 curl/7.55.1 - 404 0 2 125
```

The columns are the following:

```
date 
time 
s-ip 
cs-method 
cs-uri-stem 
cs-uri-query 
s-port 
cs-username 
c-ip 
cs(User-Agent) 
cs(Referer) 
sc-status 
sc-substatus 
sc-win32-status 
time-taken
```

I want a Pandas table that has columns for each of the columns in the log file. Note that there isn't a convenient delimiter that can be used for neat parsing, nor is there a fixed width. This is simple in Excel and is probably simple in Python, but I've been struggling for a few hours without luck. Can someone provide a full code solution for me to study, please?

UPDATE:

Wow, I am dumb. Thanks so much all. I am not familiar with the `read_csv()` function and kept googling each step: 1. how to skip rows of a log file (to skip the first 4 rows), 2. I saw examples of others using the "fields" argument, but didn't realize it could be space delimited; 3. I didn't know a `.log` file could be treated the same as a `.csv`, or rather, be used as an input for a function called `read_csv()`.

Comment: Don't worry, you are not dumb. I didn't realize I can use `read_csv` to read just about any type of plaintext file at first either. Glad that I helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use space as the separator:

```
fields = 'date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken'.split(' ')
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, skiprows=4, names=fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't space the delimiter here?

```py
pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=' ')
```

Or, to be complete:

```py
cols = 'date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken'.split(' ')
pd.read_csv('overflow.csv',
    delimiter=' ',
    comment='#',
    names=cols)
```

Gives (sliced due to size):

```py
print(df.iloc[:,-5:])
```

```
  cs(Referer)  sc-status  sc-substatus  sc-win32-status  time-taken
0           -        200             0                0          32
1           -        404             0                2         125
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file or data without delimiters. You have to read file and extract data to dict in list by regular expression. Finally convert dict in list to dataframe

Because I don't have your full dataset. Just take a piece for example below:

```
# Dataset Example
2020-03-31 00:00:40 172.31.11.70 GET 
2020-03-31 00:01:03 172.31.11.70 GET
```

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

data_list = []
column_name_list = ["Date", "Time", "IP", "Method"]
regex = r"^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b (GET|POST)$"

test_str = (
    "2020-03-31 00:00:40 172.31.11.70 GET\n"
    "2020-03-31 00:01:03 172.31.11.70 POST"
)

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    row_dict = {}
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):

        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        row_dict.update({column_name_list[groupNum]: match.group(groupNum)})
        print(row_dict)
        print(
            "Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(
                groupNum=groupNum,
                start=match.start(groupNum),
                end=match.end(groupNum),
                group=match.group(groupNum),
            )
        )
    data_list.append(row_dict)

## Output 
##           Time        IP Method
##  0  2020-03-31  00:00:40    GET
##  1  2020-03-31  00:01:03   POST
```

You need to find out your regular expression for your dataset.